# Table row sorting except first three cells using Jquery UI Sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, sortablejs

Table row sorting except first three cells using Jquery UI Sorting. I did for entire row but i need sorting in particular cells with single hover button location.

I found one [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jsjqfinder/gdkqupfz/2/). UI structure is totally different but concept is same.
My UI in this [link2](http://jsfiddle.net/jsjqfinder/6dna9pfm/49/).

Is it possible in Single Table concept?

My code:

```
#cursorrow {
    position: relative;
}

    #cursorrow i.fa.fa-arrows {
        position: absolute;
        top: -11px;
        left: -2px;
        color: #702065;
        display: none;
        cursor: move;
    }

td.customwidth.key-grid-column:hover i.fa.fa-arrows {
    display: block !important;
}

.equibackstyle.Sequence table .grid-row {
    height: 40px;
}

    .equibackstyle.Sequence table .grid-row:hover td {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }

tr.grid-row.ui-sortable-handle.ui-sortable-helper {
    height: 40px !important;
}

.equibackstyle.Sequence table .grid-row {
    height: 40px !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

---

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
         $(".sorttable").sortable();
    });
```

---

```
   <table class="table table-striped" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0;">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr style="height:0 !important">
                                                        <th class="key-grid-header-column" style="width: 10%; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;" title="" data-toggle="tooltip">
                                                            <div class="th-inner">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-header-column-text">
                                                                    Title 1
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th class="key-grid-header-column" style="width: 10%; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;" title="" data-toggle="tooltip">
                                                            <div class="th-inner">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-header-column-text">
                                                                    Title 2
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th class="key-grid-header-column" style="width: 10%; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;" title="" data-toggle=" tooltip">
                                                            <div class="th-inner">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-header-column-text">Title 3                                                                    </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th class="key-grid-header-column" style="width: 10%; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;" title="" data-toggle=" tooltip">
                                                            <div class="th-inner">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-header-column-text">Title 4                                                                    </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th class="key-grid-header-column" style="width: 10%; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;" title="" data-toggle=" tooltip">
                                                            <div class="th-inner">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-header-column-text">Title 5                                                                    </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th class="key-grid-header-column" style="width: 10%; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;" title="" data-toggle=" tooltip">
                                                            <div class="th-inner">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-header-column-text">Title 6                                                                    </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th class="key-grid-header-column" style="width: 10%; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;" title="" data-toggle=" tooltip">
                                                            <div class="th-inner">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-header-column-text">                                                                        Title 7
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th class="key-grid-header-column" style="width: 10%; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;" title="" data-toggle=" tooltip">
                                                            <div class="th-inner">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-header-column-text">Title 8                                                                    </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th class="key-grid-header-column" style="width: 10%; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;" title="" data-toggle=" tooltip">
                                                            <div class="th-inner">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-header-column-text">
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody class="sorttable"> 
                                                        <tr class="grid-row"  style="">
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column ui-state-disabled" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">50
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column ui-state-disabled" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">Days Later
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column ui-state-disabled" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    
                                                                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                                                                        <input autocomplete="off" class=" form-control key-form-control  control-max-dimension " data-old-value="01/01/0001 00:00:00" id="" max="2200-12-31" min="1900-01-01" name="" style="" type="Date" value="">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text" id="cursorrow" style=" ">
                                                                    <i class="fa  fa-arrows sortingicon" aria-hidden="true" style=" "></i>
                                                                    Minor Service
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    CO1 Chargeable Service
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    $0.00
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    1
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    3
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column ui-state-disabled" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    <ul class="list-inline" style="float:right;">
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil grid-btn " onclick="addservicefun()" title="Edit"></i>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash grid-btn " onclick="dummyedit()" title="Edit"></i>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class="grid-row" style="">
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column ui-state-disabled" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    51
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    Days Later
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    <span> 15/09/2020</span>

                                                                    
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column ui-state-disabled" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text" id="cursorrow" style=" ">
                                                                    <i class="fa  fa-arrows sortingicon" aria-hidden="true" style=" "></i>
                                                                    Minor Service
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    CO1 Chargeable Service
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    $0.00
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    1
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    3
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    <ul class="list-inline" style="float:right;">
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil grid-btn " onclick="addservicefun()" title="Edit"></i>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash grid-btn " onclick="dummyedit()" title="Edit"></i>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class="grid-row" style="">
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column ui-state-disabled" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    52
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column ui-state-disabled" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    Days Later
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    <span> 15/09/2020</span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column ui-state-disabled" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text" id="cursorrow" style=" ">
                                                                    <i class="fa  fa-arrows sortingicon" aria-hidden="true" style=" "></i>
                                                                    Minor Service
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    CO1 Chargeable Service
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    $0.00
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    1
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    3
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="customwidth key-grid-column" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width: 10%;text-align: left; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                <span class="key-grid-column-text">
                                                                    <ul class="list-inline" style="float:right;">
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil grid-btn " onclick="addservicefun()" title="Edit"></i>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash grid-btn " onclick="dummyedit()" title="Edit"></i>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
$(function() {
  $(".sorttable").sortable({
    items: "> tr:not(.no-sort)"
  }).sortable("disable");
  $(".sortables").click(function() {
    if ($(this).data("sort") == true) {
      $(this).data("sort", false).html("Locked");
      $(".sorttable").sortable("disable");
    } else {
      $(this).data("sort", true).html("Unlocked");
      $(".sorttable").sortable("enable");
    }
  })
});
```

Example based on your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/cavomzbn/7/

The key here is to add `no-sort` class to Rows that should not be sorted. User will have to "Unlock" the table to sort it.

See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not looking for an entire row. I am looking first second and third cells should be fixed and the remaining will sortable.

Comment: @WpFinder please clarify if you want them sortable in the Row or sortable in the Table. If the latter, should they remain in their Columns or can they sort in any column. Please be meticulous about your description.